# Npm install : register error parsing json

Tags: javascript, npm, npm-install

I has troubled when installed npm in windows 8. 
Step repoduce:

1. I set proxy for npm by: npm config set registry
2. Typing : npm install npm -g.

#### I found error : json parsing json npm

- ***`npm ERR! registry error parsing json`***
- *npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600*
- *`npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe"
  "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js"
  "install" "npm" "-g"`*

---

#### The error happend

```html
npm ERR! <HTML>  
npm ERR! <Head>  
npm ERR! <TITLE>404 Not Found  
npm ERR! </TITLE>  
npm ERR! </HEAD>  
npm ERR! <BODY bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><h1>  
npm ERR! 404 Not Found  
npm ERR! </h1>  
npm ERR! </BODY>
```

Comment: _when installed npm in windows 8_ Don't you have nodejs installed which bundles npm in it.

Comment: what are you trying to do with `npm install npm` ?

Comment: @ Hi John. It's truly my trouble now. 
@ Hi Jai. I has alreadly installed node 4.4.0 and npm 2.14.20.